# Best practise for converter

Tags: c#, html, design-patterns, pdf

What best practice and design patterns could you advise when creating component that convert file from one format to another, based on C#? For example PDF to HTML or Word to HTML.

Comment: What do you want design pattern to implement own converter or use any library for convert between different formats?

Comment: We need more details? What are the problems you've faced? what have you already developed?

Comment: I'm starting from zero. I want to develop converter from pdf to html. It doesn't matter why, let's think that it's just for practice. So i want to do it right. No dirty code. When we parsing pdf we're getting some entity that we must convert in html-entity, it have some conversion rules etc.

Comment: The practice of not developing your own code when excellent and affordable products are readily available.  The example is otherwise far too broad to throw a pattern at it.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes there is no product that could do this. Or we have only commercial way, no open-source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use files. Take base Stream references as input/outputs so you can bring in data from anywhere and write it anywhere (files, databases, network connections, memory, etc).

If you expect that there is any chance you will ever want to do more than one format conversion (and in my experience it's very commmon for most software to grow in scope, usually before it's released, but often soon after release), design an *extendable* internal representation that supports all the features of the other formats that are currently important/relevant to you, and use a pipeline approach that applies a double conversion (PDF -> MyFormat and then MyFormat -> HTML). That way, when you decide you also wish to convert from Word, you only have to write a Word -> MyFormat conversion to achieve Word -> HTML. This can cost very little to implement in the first place, and can give massive gains in robustness and implementation cost for each successive format you add support for.

Try to write flexible code (consider how formats might change in future). When the next PDF or Word or HTML format comes out, how easily will you be able to upgrade the code to support any changes that have been introduced? (By this, I mean, try not to put arbitrary restrictions in the conversion, like assuming that because the current format only allows 256 fonts to be used, that you can use a byte to store a font index - leave a bit of space for expansion)

Build a progress reporting system into the design from day one, so it's easy to show a progress bar during the conversion. And ensure your design that doesn't preclude batch-processing hundreds of files in one go, even if that's all you need now.

Keep the conversion code completely separate from the application that drives it; make sure the business logic (conversion) is totally divorced from any UI. The conversion(s) should be totally separate re-usable module(s), and capable of running in a batch-processing mode where there is no user interaction.